# Excel Formula to select all rows in a column except for the row which houses the formula itself

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have the following table depicted below that is utilized the organize meeting times for a company's clients. I have added a 'Status' column which uses the following formula to determine whether there is a "Clash" or "No Clash" by comparing the Columns C,D and E between row 8 and 9 (which in this case there is a clash as depicted in the following image).

```
=IF(C9<>C8,"No Clash",IF(D9<>D8, "No Clash", IF(E9<>E8, "No Clash", "Clash")))
```

[image: Company Meeting Excel Table]

My question; is there a way to modify this formula that is currently in cell F8, so that the above formula applies to all rows in columns C, D and E, except for any column values in row 8.

Comment: I am not following, can you give expected output and explanation?

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild, so my aim is, for each row in the 'Status' column I want to perform a check which compares the Start_Time, End_Time and Meeting_Room for each row against all over rows in the table, so that if the same MeetingRoom is booked for a given Start_Time and End_Time then the 'Status' column will output "Clash" as a result

Comment: Okay, and I am assuming it is any overlap in time? So 1:30->2:30 in boardroom 1 and 2:00->2:30 should read "Clash", correct?

Comment: d u expect to see `=IF(C9<>C7,"No Clash",IF(D9<>D7, "No Clash", IF(E9<>E7, "No Clash", "Clash")))` in cell F9?

Comment: Hi, Maybe just try to create a code  that goes thgough each cell starting from row 3 to last row. Won't code it for you since it's very simple and you can do it on your own . The idea is to go through each cell in range from 3 to last row-> for each cell in range x=3 to last cell<col.E>[link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) check if cells(x,3)<>cells(x-1,3) then "No Clash" Elseif cells(x,4)<>cells(x-1,4) Then "No Clash" Elseif cells(x,5)<>cells(x-1,5) Then "No Clash" Else "Clash" End if Next x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to those who commented, I ended up finding a solution for this.

What I did was a created a macro which would organize all meetings into ascending order (based on their Start_Time), where the VBA code is depicted below for this macro:

```
Sub UpdateOrder()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("C1:C1506"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("F10").Select
End Sub
```

From here I applied the following formula to each row to find if there was a clash between sequential rows:

```
=IF(AND(C16="",C17=""),"FALSE",IF(AND(C16=C17,E16=E17),"TRUE",IF(AND(C16=C15,E16=E15),"TRUE",IF(AND(D16>C17,D16<D17,E16=E17),"TRUE","FALSE"))))
```

I then added a color threshold so that the Start time is highlighted red if it clashes with the previous start time as depicted in the image below.